# Is it possible to send a text file from linux host to a windows client via command-line

Tags: linux, windows-xp

I am using emulation software to connect to a remote linux server via ssh

I am emulating wyse50 text-only terminal
I would like to transfer a text file to c:\tempdir folder on my local pc (running xp-pro)
Is it possible to that via a Bash batchfile?
Thanks
Dory

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming you're using PuTTY to connect to your Linux server via SSH? Neither PuTTY or Windows' command line can directly do file transfers without some something additional in place first. It depends if you want to use PuTTY / Windows CMD to download (pull) the file from your Linux server, or if you want to use a terminal on your Linux server to upload (push) the file to your Windows client.

If you're pulling/downloading from the Windows client side:

- Use PSCP.EXE from PuTTY to open a SCP (secure copy protocol) to your Linux server. This can upload/download files in a command line running on your Windows client. PSCP.EXE can be downloaded here: http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html

  *I'd recommend this as you won't need any additional software installed.*
- Use Windows' FTP client (FTP.EXE) to upload/download files in Windows' native command prompt. This will require an FTP server to be installed on your Linux server though, such as vsftpd or proftpd. A decent guide for Windows' FTP.EXE is here: http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/164/tn_16418.html

If you're pushing/uploading from the Linux server side:

- You WILL have to install an FTP server on your Windows machine to receive a file from a Linux FTP client, such as FileZila Server. You can then use the Linux FTP command to connect to your Windows client and push the file to it: http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_ftp.htm

  *I'd recommend this option least of all.*

Answer (score 0):

The "best" solutions would imply modifying the server and or Windows box to make this easier (so you can use scp, ftp, SAMBA/Windows File sharing, NFS or similar).

As it sounds like none of those might be options, the easiest way may be to start a log file on the terminal emulator, cat the file, capture the output and then close the log file - editing out the bit at the top (and maybe bottom) showing the commands manually afterwards.

I've never used a wyse50 terminal, but was around in the "BBS" days (prior to the wide use of the Internet), and the standard way to do what you are trying to do would be to install a program like "zmodem" on the server (alternatives include "xmodem","kermit","bimodem" among others, but "zmodem is where I would start because it was simple and ubiquitous") and ensure the terminal emulator had support for it, then issue a command to send the program with xmodem and it would be capured to your system.  I'd be willing to bet this could be made to work if your terminal emulator supports it - and most will.  (Try using the program "sz" to initiate a transfer)